# Как добавить проект react на хостинг firebase?

Tags: firebase

Я пробую загрузить свой проект на хостинг firebase, все делал по инструкции и вроде все работает, но рендерится только index.html. Может быть я сделал что-то не так во время инициализации проекта?

Comment: очень много нюансов может быть по настройке вашего проекта.

Answer (score 0):

1. Пишешь `npm run build`
2. `firebase init`
3. Выбираешь hosting (папку вместо public пишешь build)
4. `firebase deploy --only hosting`